# Cartesian product of two sets where each set contains the empty element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

What is the Cartesian product of these two sets:
$$
A = \{\emptyset, 2\}\\
B = \{\emptyset, 3\}
$$
I am guessing it is
$$
\{\emptyset, 2, 3, \{\emptyset, \emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, 3\}, \{2, \emptyset\}, \{2, 3\}\}
$$

but the cardinality of a Cartesian product is always $2^n$, but there are 7 elements, is this because there exists two empty sets, one from each set A and B but they are the same element, hence the removal of the redundant one?

Edit: What I did to get the sets A and B was to take the power set of
$$
A = {2} \\
B = {3} \\
P(A) = \{\emptyset, 2\} \\
P(B) = \{\emptyset, 3\} \\
P(A) \times P(B) = \{\emptyset, 2\} \times\{\emptyset, 3\}
$$

Comment: Where does $\emptyset$ come from: is that an ordered pair?

Comment: $\emptyset$, $2$, and $3$ are not elements of $A\times B$.

Comment: Empty set, $2$ and $3$ do not belong to the cartesian product .There are only four elements.

Comment: The elements of a Cartesian product is always ordered pairs. None of the elements in your set is an ordered pair.

Comment: Look at my edit, I added why I have got the empty set in both sets. "If S is a finite set with $|S| = n$ elements, then the number of subsets of S is $|P(S)| = 2^n$" quote from wikipedia about power sets

Comment: What do power sets have to do with cartesian products?

Comment: I have a question where you take the power set of two elements and then take the cartesian product of that power set. I am completely lost and there is no answer in the book. There is no example of this in the book and googling it does nothing for me since nobody has asked this question as far as I can see.

Comment: @linker You claim "I have a question where you take the power set of two elements and then take the cartesian product of that power set.". But that's not the question you *asked* here. The question you **asked** has nothing to do with power sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a set $A$ and a set $B$, every element of $A\times B$ must be of the form $(a,b)$ where $a$ is an element of $A$ and $b$ is an element of $B$.

In the case of $\emptyset, 2, 3$, this is not true. It is not true that $\emptyset=(a,b)$ for any pair of values $a\in A, b\in B$.

This is also not true for other elements of your solution. $\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}$ is **not** an element of $A\times B$, because it is not an ordered pair of two elements. In fact, $\{\emptyset,\emptyset\}=\{\emptyset\}.$

Also:

> but the cardinality of a Cartesian product is always $2^n$

Not true. The cardinality of a Cartesian product of two finite sets $A$ and $B$ is $|A|\cdot |B|$.

Comment: What is the cartesian product of two tuples where they have a common element then? e.g: $A=\{1, 2\},B=\{1, 3\}$

Comment: @linker $A$ and $B$ are not tuples. They are sets. And the cartesian product is still the same, i.e. the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. This definition says nothing about whether $a$ and $b$ can or can't be the same.

Comment: So $A\times B=\{\{1, 1\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 1\}, \{2, 3\}\} = \{\{1\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 1\}, \{2, 3\}\}$?

Comment: @linker No. $\{1,1\}$ is not an ordered pair. $(1,1)$ **is** an ordered pair. Check your textbook or notes for the definition of "ordered pair". Note that there is a difference between $(a,a)$ and $\{a,a\}$.

Comment: Oh ok so $A \times B = \{(1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3)}$ but what about $A = \{\emptyset, 1\}, B = \{\emptyset, 3\}$

Comment: @linker Why would that be any different?

Comment: $A \times B = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset), (\emptyset, 3), (1, \emptyset), (1, 3)\}$ thanks :)

Comment: @linker Don't forget to accept my answer if it is what you needed.